# How can I skip printing an SQL script but still show the DBMS values?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm developing a code and would like to see in the results only the actual values, instead of the script I executed.

So I'm trying to develop a "table rows counter" and I've been quite successful, but I still get the full executed script, when I only need its results.

Let's say, my code is:

```
DECLARE
VAR_1 NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
    SELECT IMITM INTO VAR_1 FROM PRODDTA.F4101 WHERE ROWNUM <= 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DUMMY TEST 1' || VAR_1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DUMMY TEST 2');

END;
/
```

Well, by clicking F5 I would see:

```
DUMMY TEST 150041087
DUMMY TEST 2
 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

In the complete code it reads about 200 lines of only code, so...

How can I get only the output lines, and in this case, remove the "PL/SQL procedure..." legend?

I've tried unsuccessfully yo use "SET FEED" and "SET TERM" off.

Comment: There is no F5 or clicking in SQL\*Plus. Are you sure this isn’t PL/SQL Developer or TOAD or something else? If it is SQL\*Plus, what is your `echo` setting?

Comment: I actually managed to do it. Will post what I did.

Comment: Did you set echo off? Normally the script itself is not printed when you run it, and `echo on` is the only setting that would do this. Also, I’d still be interested to know what  tool you are using.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I would have gotten the script before my results. Verify Off removed it & let me with the DBMS Output only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to do it by exploring SET commands.

For the SQL script "acknolwedgement", we can skip it with the following commands:

To disable the SQL & variables verification before the actual execution, use:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
```

To disable the post execution notes, as Tejash indicated already, use:

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
```

So my prologue ends up being:

```
SET SERVERTOUTPUT ON;
SET VERIFY OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
```

Thanks a lot for the answers & comments.

Comment: In your question you said you got "the full executed script". From this answer it sounds like you didn't.

Comment: Yes, before the Verify Off, I would get the full executed script displayed before the actual execution, when they only desirable output was the actual DBMS messages.

Comment: Was the script all one one line? `verify` only affects lines containing substitution variables.

Comment: No, the script had several lines.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm):

> SET FEEDBACK OFF also turns off the statement confirmation messages
>   such as 'Table created' and 'PL/SQL procedure successfully completed'
>   that is displayed after successful SQL or PL/SQL statements.

You need to use `SET FEEDBACK OFF` as following:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
SQL> SET FEEDBACK OFF
SQL> DECLARE
  2      VAR_1   NUMBER := 0;
  3  BEGIN
  4      SELECT
  5          1
  6      INTO VAR_1
  7      FROM
  8          DUAL
  9      WHERE
 10          ROWNUM <= 1;
 11
 12      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DUMMY TEST 1' || VAR_1);
 13      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DUMMY TEST 2');
 14  END;
 15  /
DUMMY TEST 11
DUMMY TEST 2
SQL>
SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi, not sure this resolves. I'm using first SET SERVEROUT ON; followed by SET FEEDBACK OFF; & I still get the full SQL script reference, instead of only my DBMS outputs. However, it did remove the “PL/SQL” sentence.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to remove, for example in your query's output, the executed SQL & the commands in order to get only the DBMSs?

Comment: Btw, my tool is Toad for Oracle v 11.~.

Comment: So this was a Toad question all along? It was tagged as SQL\*Plus, not Toad.